# Javascript object as an argument equals undefined in IE6-8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object, undefined

Have a question... I have a code that work everywhere but in IE6-8. In the beginning I define the object changeableElements (elements properties of which will be changed). Then I pass this object to function called changeCSS() as an argument. So, in IEs that object becomes equal undefined... How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

http://spezlib.p-design.org - The site
http://spezlib.p-design.org/resources/javascript/other.js - The script itself

Comment: if you found an answer to your own question you should add it as an answer and click the check mark to mark it solved. Do not change the title of the question.

Comment: @Dour High Arch, thanks, I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: in for in loops IE doesn't recognize left identifier if it's not preceeded by 'var' keyword... (i.e. `for (item in elements)` is wrong, should be `for (var item in elements)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `changeCSS` that has no arguments:

```
changeCSS();
getPreviousContrast();
changeContrast();
```

Change that first line to `changeCSS(..., changeableElements)` with `...` replaced by whatever it is that should be there. Honestly I'm surprised it works in any browsers.